# set panoramaItem list background image

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

How can i set a background image for a panoramaItem's ListBox ?

I have this panorama item :

```
 <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Shopping list"  >

<ListBox x:Name="List"  ItemsSource="{Binding rList}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewModelTemplate}"  >
</ListBox>

</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

and would like to have an image as the background for this list item ( a notebook image). How can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `ListBox's` `Background` like this,

```
            <ListBox x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding rList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewModelTemplate}"> 
                <ListBox.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
                </ListBox.Background>
```